# Building a better staged 1's complement adder tree?

Tags: vhdl, adder

I'm trying to calculate the checksum of IPv4 and UDP messages coming out of my Ethernet controller module. The checksum calculation for both IPv4 and UDP is defined as 1's complement addition, which means add most header fields and the entire message payload by 16-bit operands, add the carries back into the operands, and take the bitwise NOT of the result.

I can do this in a staged approach. I first calculate the checksum words in this manner as the message is received (outside of the block in question - that does just fine). I then pass this along with the message itself to the next block, which needs to calculate both the IPv4 and UDP checksums before the IPv4 block writes the IPv4 checksum field. It does this in stages, halving the number of operands. But I still need to calculate carries afterward, and all of this together means the final answer IPv4 checksum doesn't propagate through in time to be written in the checksum field. Here is a snippet of the first few stages of my adder tree (concat_string : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := "0000000000000000";):

```
-------------------- IPv4 CALCS --------------------
      -- Stage 1 sums
      isum1 <= unsigned('0' & vide)                        + unsigned('0' & eth_len_int(15 downto 0));
      isum2 <= unsigned('0' & ip_id)                       + unsigned('0' & offset);
      isum3 <= unsigned('0' & TTLProto);
      isum4 <= unsigned('0' & ip_src(31 downto 16))        + unsigned('0' & ip_src(15 downto 0));
      isum5 <= unsigned('0' & ip_dest(31 downto 16))       + unsigned('0' & ip_dest(15 downto 0));
      isum6 <= unsigned('0' & src_port)                    + unsigned('0' & dest_port);
      isum7 <= unsigned('0' & tcpudp_len_int(15 downto 0)) + unsigned('0' & tcpudp_chksum_int(15 downto 0));
      -- Stage 1 carries
      ic1   <= unsigned(concat_string & isum1(16)) + unsigned(concat_string & isum2(16));
      ic2   <= unsigned(concat_string & isum3(16)) + unsigned(concat_string & isum4(16));
      ic3   <= unsigned(concat_string & isum5(16)) + unsigned(concat_string & isum6(16));
      ic4   <= unsigned(concat_string & isum7(16));
  
      -- Stage 2 sums
      isum8  <= unsigned('0' & isum1(15 downto 0)) + unsigned('0' & isum2(15 downto 0));
      isum9  <= unsigned('0' & isum3(15 downto 0)) + unsigned('0' & isum4(15 downto 0));
      isum10 <= unsigned('0' & isum5(15 downto 0)) + unsigned('0' & isum6(15 downto 0));
      isum11 <= unsigned('0' & isum7(15 downto 0));
      -- Stage 2 carries
      ic5    <= unsigned('0' & ic1(15 downto 0)) + unsigned('0' & ic2(15 downto 0));
      ic6    <= unsigned('0' & ic3(15 downto 0)) + unsigned('0' & ic4(15 downto 0));
      ic7    <= unsigned(concat_string & isum8(16))  + unsigned(concat_string & isum9(16));
      ic8    <= unsigned(concat_string & isum10(16)) + unsigned(concat_string & isum11(16));
      
      -- Stage 3 sums
      isum12 <= unsigned('0' & isum8(15 downto 0))  + unsigned('0' & isum9(15 downto 0));
      isum13 <= unsigned('0' & isum10(15 downto 0)) + unsigned('0' & isum11(15 downto 0));
      -- Stage 3 carries
      ic9    <= unsigned('0' & ic5(15 downto 0)) + unsigned('0' & ic6(15 downto 0));
      ic10   <= unsigned('0' & ic7(15 downto 0)) + unsigned('0' & ic8(15 downto 0));
      ic11   <= unsigned(concat_string & isum12(16)) + unsigned(concat_string & isum13(16));
```

I know there should be a way to calculate [sum = unsigned(x) + unsigned(y) + carry of x+y] written cleanly in one clock cycle instead of two. What's the most legible way to do this?

Comment: Can you XNOR all the bits?

Comment: XNOR-ing the bits might not work. I still need to swing the 17th bit of these 16-bit additions (carry) back into them so it is A+B+carry. Only the final result is actually straightforward negated (unless that's all 0's, then it's all 1's as all 0's is reserved).

Comment: You can write your own function. VHDL would permit you to make a 1's comp package (along the lines of numeric_std) but much simpler, encompassing only what you need : that would even let you use the "+" operator on your 1's comp type as the function's name, without operator overload resolution problems.

Comment: That's very interesting, I'd love to see how this can be used to take out some clock cycles.